# C# Marshal array to struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

I'm trying to use Marshal to copy an array to a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1,Size = 14)]
public struct RDShifterGearDecrease
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4,SizeConst =4)]
    public UInt32 PosReduceGear;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst = 4)]
    public UInt32 PosReturnCenter;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2, SizeConst = 2)]
    public UInt16 BlipTimeBeforeDecreaseGear;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2, SizeConst = 2)]
    public UInt16 TimeoutGearDecrease;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2, SizeConst = 2)]
    public UInt16 TimeoutReturnCenter;
}
```

My Array is:

```
[0]=0;
[1]=1;
[2]=5;
[3]=4;
...
[13]=0;
```

The method I use to copy is:

```
 private static T FillObjectWithData<T>(byte[] arr)
 {
      T str = default(T);
       try
       {
           int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
           IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
           Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);
           str = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
           Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
       }
       return str;
 }
```

The value of the first variable `PosReduceGear` for example, I would like to be `0x0154 = 340`, but its given me `0x04050100 = 67436800`.

I understand why, and would like to avoid manipulating the array before copy. There is something on the struct that I can do?

Comment: even if the endianness was reversed, how do you think four bytes 0 1 5 4 would equal 0x154? they would be 0x00105040

Comment: Yes, I know, but i receive this array in a custom protocol that sends a ascii hex char (to be printable). There are something that I can do directly in the struct or just doing some work on the array?

Comment: You need to throw this code away to get ahead, it does not do what you think it does.  Google "c# how to parse a hex string".

Comment: Ok, I did some work on the array, now I got  [0]=0x01 and [1]=0x54. But when copy, the endianness got reversed. How to invert it dynamically?